Filtering a Power BI report using OR conditions
I have a Power BI report connected to an SSAS Cube. The dimension I'm pulling from has 3 discrete fields - SO1, SO2, and SO3. It's easy enough of course to filter a visual on these individually, but I need to be able to filter on all 3 as if there were an OR condition between them. How can I achieve this seemingly simple task given that this is not an import model report?
I realize that one option would be to change the structure of the data in the dimension and UNION these into a single column but then that's going to create multiple records so I'd prefer not to do that if possible.
